# how update occurs in mysql memcached ndb cluster

Tags: mysql, database, caching, memcached, cluster-computing

I know **memcached** but  i dont familiar with mysql ndb cluster with memcached.i want to know that how update occurs in **ndb cluster**. means it first update in memcached and then i ndb or wait till DB update and then memcached will updated.

Also how much impact on index value that is not key in DB when update occurs in memcached?
Thanx for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the update is sent to the database.  If it succeeds, and the cache policy enables local cache, then it is also stored in the memcached server.